# jquery use a datepicker on more pages

Tags: jquery

I have this in my javascript file:

```
$("#birthdate").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            altFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            altField: '#birthdate',

             });
```

I have various pages which have fields that need a datepicker. Sometimes even more then one datepicker on a page. How can I be sure that this is also going to work for a field that has for example class name "alternateDate"?

I tried

```
 $("#birthdate #alternateDate").datepicker({
```

But that's not going to work.

Any idea's?

**Update:**

Hmm still got a problem with the date format.

```
$.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy');
            $(".datepicker").datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
             });
```

Here is my html

```
<label for="geboortedatum">Geboortedatum <em>*</em></label><br/><input type="text" class="datepicker" id="birthdate" name="birthdate" value="{$birthdate}"><br/>
```

But the format in the datepicker input field is still shown as 04/01/2009

meaning mm/dd/yy

Any idea's?

Answer (score 4):

How about adding a class to the fields you want to turn into date pickers.  For example:

```
<input type="text" id="birthDate" class="MyDatePickers">
<input type="text" id="alternateDate" class="MyDatePickers">
```

Which you can activate with:

```
$(".MyDatePickers").datepicker({
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true,
                    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
                     });
```

Comment: +1: Using classes like this would be best. @Sanders: You don't need to specify the altField if it's the same as the controlID.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you are referring to two id's (because of the symbol #). Maybe you can try to iterate through the collection of alternateDate elements:

> $('#birthdate.alternateDate').each(function(index){
>   $(this).datepicker({...}) });

Disclaimer: I do not know the exact jquery iteration syntax, but I'm positive it is something like this.

Comment: Miguel,

You might not have understood my question well. What I mean to say is that #birthdate and #alternateDate are not necessarily on the same page.
So I want to have one datePicker function but i want it to be used not only by an input field which has the class birthDate but also by some other classes.

How can I accomplish this?